# Изменение данных в таблице MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector

Возникла проблема. Надо изменять колонку pass в БД Mysql через C#. То есть, пользователь вводит в текстбоксы имя и пароль. Эта информация с текстбоксов ищется по двум колонкам login и pass. И если данные с текстбоксов равны login и pass соответственно, то пользователь через третий текстбокс может изменить информацию в колонке pass.

В интернете искал либо не то что мне надо, или же совсем не понятно.

Также я создал класс и написал код, который проверяет есть ли пользователь.

```
// Собственно сам класс
class DBIO
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=user;password=qwerty;database=bu57ga2dx9");

    public void openConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
    public void closedConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
```

```
//  Код проверки пользователя
String Loginu = LoginBox.Text;
String Passu = PassBox.Text;

DBIO db = new DBIO();

DataTable table = new DataTable();

MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `pass` = @uP", db.getConnection());
command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Loginu;
command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Passu;

adapter.SelectCommand = command;
adapter.Fill(table);
if (table.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: ну Select вы делать умеете, осталось научиться делать Update - принцип тот же самый, что у вас сейчас.

Comment: Все,я понял что было,надо писать вместо SELECT UPDATE это первое,но самое главное adapter.Fill(table) и именно fill не update это было моей ошибкой

Comment: [Updating example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters#example)